# API integrates and return the value in ajax

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, ajax, jquery

I have integrated the third party `API` for validating a correct email address with the domain. The `API` call is returning the value in the ajax call as Boolean.

How to retrieve the value from the `API` response in ajax?

Comment: Please share your JS code.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to handle ajax requests with jquery is:

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function( serverResponse) {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

The `done` function will be called if request is successfull, and `serverResponse` variable contains the returned values from your server.

See: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: We can get the value in alert and not able to pass it to another function. I need to retrieve the value and based on that need to display error message